# How to find the second angle of the Arc

Tags: javascript, c#, math, geometry, trigonometry

I have a arc of circle that contains the two Angle. I know only the Angle-1 and it's position (x1, y1) and Angle-2 position (x2, y2).But i don't know the Angle-2, center position and radius etc..

Please refer the below image for my requirement.
[image]

Is it possible to find the Angle-2 value. Please suggest me the formula to find the solution.

Thanks,
Bharathi.

Comment: Is `(x1,y1)` always on the x-axis? Also, is `(x2,y2)` always on the circle?

Comment: You know angle-2's position but you don't know angle-2? Do you mean that you know the second endpoint?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog yes.. i know only the second end point..

Comment: If you know *only* the two endpoints then I'm afraid that is not enough; you need *at least* two more pieces of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the given answer has left the solution open, of sorts, as not everyone knows how to solve simultaneous equations. MBo's answer can be written as follows

Given `x1`,`y1` and `x2`,`y2` and an angle `a` from an unknown center to the point  `x1`,`y1` find the center of the circle and the angle `angle` from `x2`,`y2` to the center point.

```
mx = (x2 - x1) / 2;
my = (y2 - y1) / 2;
u = (cos(a) * my -  sin(a) * mx) / (cos(a) * mx + sin(a) * my);
t = (my - mx * u ) / sin(a);
```

The center point of the circle is

```
cx = x1 + cos(a) * t;
cy = y1 + sin(a) * t;
```

The angle from `x2`,`y2` to the center point is

```
angle = a + atan(u) * 2;
```

Note as MBo pointed out, not all values for `x1`,`y1`,`x2`,`y2` and `a` have a valid solution.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 400;

function test (a,a1){

    r = 100;
    cx = 200;
    cy = 200
    x1 = cx + Math.cos(a) * r;
    y1 = cy + Math.sin(a) * r;

    // use a test angle  x2,y2
    x2 = cx + Math.cos(a1) * r;
    y2 = cy + Math.sin(a1) * r;

    mx = (x2 - x1) / 2;
    my = (y2 - y1) / 2;

    u = (Math.cos(a) * my -  Math.sin(a) * mx) / (Math.cos(a) * mx + Math.sin(a) * my);
    t = (my - mx * u ) / Math.sin(a);
    
    u = Math.atan(u)*2;

    // use calculated angle and radius to get the center point from x2,y2
    cx = x2 - Math.cos(a + u) * t;
    cy = y2 - Math.sin(a + u) * t;
    
    
    ctx.clear();   

    // draw line from center to x1,y1
    ctx.line(cx,cy,x1,y1);
    
    // draw cross for calculated center and draw circle using calculated radius 
    ctx.cross(cx,cy,2,"blue");
    ctx.strokeCircle(cx,cy,Math.abs(t))
    // draw line from calculated center to x2,y2
    ctx.line(cx,cy,x2,y2,2,"red");
    
    // draw starting points 
    ctx.cross(cx,cy,2);
    ctx.cross(x1,y1);
    ctx.cross(x2,y2);

}

var angle = 0;
var angle2 = 0;
function update(timer){
    angle += 0.01;
    angle2 += 0.02;
    test(angle,angle2);
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);



// Some render functions to display the result.
ctx.strokeCircle = function(x,y,r){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x + r,y);
    ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.stroke();
}
ctx.line = function(x,y,xx,yy,w=1,col="black"){
    ctx.lineWidth = w;
    ctx.strokeStyle = col;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x,y);
    ctx.lineTo(xx,yy);
    ctx.stroke();        
}
ctx.cross = function(x,y,w=1,col="black",size = 5){
  ctx.line(x-size,y-size,x+size,y+size,w,col);
  ctx.line(x+size,y-size,x-size,y+size,w,col);
}
ctx.clear = function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}
```

```css
canvas { border : 2px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: the given solution is not working for me. fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/pcfkjLg1/ . I create lin from first circle 0 angle to 270. And pls note, the second circle centerX value is always same of the first circle 0 degree X position

Comment: The second circle should touch the 0 degree and 270 degree of first circle.

Comment: @Bharathi You have some errors in your code. You need to make sure all the angles are in radians. You are calculating `u` using `a = 90` it should be `(Math.PI / 2)` there are also some other logic errors, the center `(cx,cy)` is `(50,100)` and but you set `x1,y1` to `(100,100)` and the angle as 90 but from `(50,100)` to `(100,100)` is 0 deg not 90. The answer works I have tested it thoroughly and just testxted it once again incase there is as typo. I will add a JS demo when I get a chance.

Comment: Thank  you soo much.. Angle to radian only the problem.. (cx,cy), (x1,y1) is correct. https://jsfiddle.net/pcfkjLg1/1/ ..

Comment: @Bharathi oh I and just added a demo. Good that you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand this problem:
You have point (x1,y1) that lies on a circle and radius to this point forms angle Fi. And you have another point (x2,y2) that lies on the same circle.
[image]

So we know direction to the center from the first point

```
u = (-sin(fi), -cos(fi))
```

and perpendicular to the middle of segment between two points is line through center too. Note that not all positions of point 2 give solution.

So you have parametric equation of the first line

```
x = x1 - cos(fi) * t      //eqs 1
y = y1 - sin(fi) * t
```

and for the second line

```
 base point 
 mx = (x1 + x2) / 2
 my = (y1 + y2) / 2
 direction vector
 dx = (-y2 + y1) / 2
 dy = (x2 - x1) / 2
```

Its parametric equation

```
  x = mx + dx * u    //eqs 2
  y = my + dy * u
```

Solve equation system

```
  x1 - cos(fi) * t = mx + dx * u
  y1 - sin(fi) * t = my + dy * u
```

for unknowns t,u and you will find point of intersection C - center of circle

Comment: The given solution is not working for me. fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/pcfkjLg1/ . I create line from first circle 0 angle to 270. And pls note, the second circle centerX value is always same of the first circle 0 degree X position. The second circle should touch the 0 degree and 270 degree of first circle

Comment: `solution is not working for me` - It is because your question is quite vague and power of my crystal ball was insufficient.